# Можно ли получит параметр `flatMap` в стриме?

Tags: java, java-stream

Ситуация следующая: у меня есть цикл в цикле (вложенный цикл) и я хочу заменить этот код на лямбда выражение. В цикле я могу обратиться к внешнему объекту. Как мне это сделать для лямбда выражения?

Можно ли получит параметр `flatMap` в стриме ?

```
 list.stream().flatMap(a -> a.getBs().stream()).forEach(b->System.out.print(a));
```

Предположим у меня нет обратной связи от `a` к `b`

Comment: А что мешает написать `list.stream().forEach(a -> a.getBs().stream().forEach(b -> System.out.print(a)));`? Зачем обязательно делать `flatMap`?

Comment: Написать ничего не мешает также как и не мешает сделать через циклы, но как мне кажется `flatMap` и был придуман для того чтобы избегать таких конструкций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам для этой задачи хочется использовать стримы (кстати, зачем? раз вы сталкиваетесь с трудностями, может быть цикл будет более разумным решением?), то найдите способ доставить в конец цепочки и значение `a` и  `b`. Поскольку в java нет кортежей, создайте свой класс-контейнер для пары значений:

```
public class Pair<A, B> {
    public final A fst;
    public final B snd;
    public Pair(A a, B b) { fst = a; snd = b; }
}
```

и мапьте ваш список в stream пар:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.getBs().stream().map(b -> new Pair(a, b)))
    .forEach(pair -> System.out.print(pair.fst));
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream, как следует из его названия - это поток, что "вытекло" из одной операции, то и поступит в другую.

Comment: Ситуация следующая: у меня есть цикл в цикле (вложенный цикл) и я хочу заменить этот код на лямбда выражение. В цикле я могу обратиться к внешнему объекту. Как мне это сделать для лямбда выражения?